# ELK - Elastic search not displaying new messages

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

Considering a situation where I have this piece of code written which is logging using dotnet standard logger

```
using(_logger.BeginScope("RequestId", DateTime.Now.Ticks))
{
     //do some work
}
```

which basically adds a scope variable in the context of the further log calls.

If for some reason, I decide to change the data type of that property to string let say as shown below

```
using(_logger.BeginScope("RequestId", Guid.NewGuid()))
{
     //do some work
}
```

I couldn't see any logs in the kibana dashboard. I am suspecting that it's happening because of the data type change. I had to delete the index from kibana and only after that I was able to see the logs.

Is this an expected behaviour? If so, what are the best practices to avoid this as this could be really painful if in our code we have the same property name-sharing multiple data types in a different context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, in elasticsearch the documents fields can only have one data type, if you do not create a [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/explicit-mapping.html) for your index, then the first time you try to index a document into that index elasticsearch will try to infer the type of the field, and it will only allow data that have the same data type.

In your example your field `RequestId` was probably indexed as a date type field, so elasticsearch will only index documents where the `RequestId` is a date type.

When you tried to index `RequestId` as a string, elasticsearch rejected the document, you can look into the logs and you will see the rejections.

If you did the opposite, indexed first as a string and after that as a date type, you wouldn't have got an error, but the date would be treated as a string, you wouldn't be able to make range and date queries in this field.

Depending of your use case you could map your fields before indexing as keyword or text, the strings type in elasticsearch, but you will only be able to the operations and searches using those fields as strings, if for example they have numbers, you wouldn't be able to sum them using elasticsearch.

You can read more about mapping in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. i want to understand it more closely.
e.g.
_logger.Information("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed:000} ms.", position, elapsedMs);
Suppose in an existing application we are logging position property as an integer in the first place. Then a new feature came in where we have a model in which the position property is of type string and developer just try to put the logging there with the similar syntax but logging as String. In this scenario, the developer won't see any logs for the later use case. So, just trying to understand the best possible ways to tackle this.

Comment: In this case if you do not want to do numeric operations with the position field, like, max, min, sum, avg, then you should store this field as keyword, but you will need to explicitly create your mapping when creating your index otherwise elastic will see a numbe and will map the field as numeric and your second case will fail. The best way is to not mix up data types for the same field name. You can also use different index for each application for example.